# OpenVSP and "no rule to build target"

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build [OpenVSP](http://openvsp.org/wiki/doku.php?id=ubuntu_instructions#instructions_for_ubuntu_1604) from source on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have managed to follow the instructions successfully so far - until I got to the line **make package**.

Whereupon, when I run the command `make package`, I got the error "no rule to build target".

My first instinct, was to look for the target 'package' in the Makefile (given below):

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.5

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /opt/OpenVSP/Libraries

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /opt/OpenVSP/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /opt/OpenVSP/build/CMakeFiles /opt/OpenVSP/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /opt/OpenVSP/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named FLTK

# Build rule for target.
FLTK: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 FLTK
.PHONY : FLTK

# fast build rule for target.
FLTK/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/FLTK.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/FLTK.dir/build
.PHONY : FLTK/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named CPPTEST

# Build rule for target.
CPPTEST: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CPPTEST
.PHONY : CPPTEST

# fast build rule for target.
CPPTEST/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/CPPTEST.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/CPPTEST.dir/build
.PHONY : CPPTEST/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named CODEELI

# Build rule for target.
CODEELI: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CODEELI
.PHONY : CODEELI

# fast build rule for target.
CODEELI/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/CODEELI.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/CODEELI.dir/build
.PHONY : CODEELI/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named EIGEN

# Build rule for target.
EIGEN: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 EIGEN
.PHONY : EIGEN

# fast build rule for target.
EIGEN/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/EIGEN.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/EIGEN.dir/build
.PHONY : EIGEN/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named LIBIGES

# Build rule for target.
LIBIGES: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 LIBIGES
.PHONY : LIBIGES

# fast build rule for target.
LIBIGES/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/LIBIGES.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/LIBIGES.dir/build
.PHONY : LIBIGES/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... FLTK"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... CPPTEST"
    @echo "... CODEELI"
    @echo "... EIGEN"
    @echo "... LIBIGES"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

The target 'package' does not exist in the MakeFile.

When I run `make`, I get the following output:

```
Built target FLTK
Built target CPPTEST
Built target CODEELI
Built target EIGEN
Built target LIBIGES
```

However, the final binary (vps), is not built. Has anyone been able to build OpenVSP on Ubuntu 16.0.4 - and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Note that [step 6 of the documentation](http://openvsp.org/wiki/doku.php?id=ubuntu_instructions#instructions_for_ubuntu_1604) does acknowledge the fact that `make package` might fail and suggests it may be the result of an incorrect `python` version.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I did read that. Those issues are not applicable to my system. I have the `fluid` executable, and also, the environment in which I'm building this has Python 3.x as the default Python. The thing is that I dont understand how the command `make package` can be correct if the **package** target is missing in the Makefile. Am I missing something?